# Boot lagging caused by text output

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop and the boot process is very fast (< 3 seconds).
On a installed Ubuntu 22.10 Server the boot sequence is pretty slow (> 60 seconds).

I try to do a graphical boot but I failed.

In order to enable the graphical boot I did :

```
grim@main:~$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical
[sudo] password for grim: 
grim@main:~$
```

Unfortunately the slow boot remains unchanged.

[image]

HDD is fast:
[image]

`systemd-analyze critical-chain multi-user.target` said:

```
grim@main:~$ sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain multi-user.target
[sudo] password for grim: 
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

multi-user.target @12.567s
└─apport.service @8.602s +21ms
  └─remote-fs.target @8.597s
    └─remote-fs-pre.target @8.593s
grim@main:~$
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145616/discussion-on-question-by-grim-boot-lagging-caused-by-text-output); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I had an interesting similar issue. I copied a VM drive to a physical server and this config got inherited from a VM

```
# grep -rF ttyS0 /etc/
/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg:GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0"
```

`ttyS0` means very different things for a VM and a physical server. For a physical server it's a physical device which was so slow that my boot time was bounded by how many lines per second it was possible to send to `ttyS0`.

systemd-analyze doesn't help in this case because the error happens before systemd starts

After I removed the line from config and run `update-grub2` my issue was solved and boot time improved by 3 minutes.

Comment: *spikes* is confusing, it makes me think "lots of similar output", which in that context would mean lots of output within a short timeframe. I suspect you mean the opposite - that nothing has been output for a while, and the timestamp jumps markedly between consecutive lines. Either way, please clarify.

Comment: @MartinKealey fixed